# Swing TableHeader with JCheckBox does not work in Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

so I am using the following renderer to render a JCheckBox in a table header on a specific column.
However, this does not work when using the Nimbus theme in the application while it works in other themes.
Any idea how I could make this renderer work, across themes?

Dracula theme: [dracula themed table header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23oLo.png)
Nimbus theme: [nimbus themed table header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KITXq.png)

Usage:

```java
JTableHeader tblHeader = myTable.getTableHeader();
tblHeader.setDefaultRenderer(new CheckHeaderRenderer(tblHeader, tblHeader.getDefaultRenderer()));
```

And the renderer:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckHeaderRenderer
implements TableCellRenderer
{
    private final JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();
    private final TableCellRenderer wrappedRenderer;
    private final java.util.List<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public CheckHeaderRenderer(final JTableHeader header, final TableCellRenderer r)
    {
        this.wrappedRenderer = r;

        check.setOpaque(false);
        check.setFont(header.getFont());
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JTable table = ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).getTable();
                TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
                int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
                int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);

                if (modelColumn != 0) { return; }

                check.setSelected(! check.isSelected());
                TableModel model = table.getModel();

                for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
                {
                    model.setValueAt(check.isSelected(), i, 0);
                }

                ((JTableHeader) e.getSource()).repaint();

                // run registered servers
                for (final ActionListener al : listeners) {
                    al.actionPerformed(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)
    {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable tbl, Object val, boolean isS, boolean hasF, int row, int col
    ) {
        JLabel lbl = (JLabel) this.wrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(tbl, val, isS, hasF, row, col);
        lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

        if (0 != col) {
            lbl.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0 ,10));
        }

        if (0 == col)
        {
            lbl.setIcon(new CheckBoxIcon(check));
            lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }

        return lbl;
    }

    private static class CheckBoxIcon
    implements Icon
    {
        private final JCheckBox check;

        public CheckBoxIcon(JCheckBox check) {
            this.check = check;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return check.getPreferredSize().width;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return check.getPreferredSize().height;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, check, (Container) c, x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: @NomadMaker: how to correctly render a checkbox that works, regardless of look&feel.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the information that you put here. People should not have to look at comments to understand the question.

Comment: Please create an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) for the code. In other words, the smallest file that will let anybody compile and test this bug.

Comment: Please tell us what is your current ouput and what is your expected output